# Lauch default editor (like 'webbrowser' module)

Tags: python, command-line, editor

Is there a simple way to lauch the systems default editor from a Python command-line tool, like the [webbrowser](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html) module?

Comment: Which filetype? For .txt and .py, opening with default application is good enough. For other filetypes, you might not get an editor.

Comment: In my case I need to edit .xml and normal text (like commit messag in svn).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Under windows you can simply "execute" the file and the default action will be taken:

`os.system('c:/tmp/sample.txt')`

For this example a default editor will spawn. Under UNIX there is an environment variable called `EDITOR`, so you need to use something like:

`os.system('%s %s' % (os.getenv('EDITOR'), filename))`

Comment: Mac users don't get any love?

Comment: And what if `EDITOR` is unset?

Comment: @exhuma if $EDITOR isn't set then you don't have *user-set* default to work with.  On OS X you can `subprocess.call(["open, "<file-path>"])` to use the default application, just like if you used the GUI.  On linux you can `subprocess.call(["xdg-open", "<file-path>"])` like @u0b34a0f6ae suggested.  `suprocess` is used here instead of `system` since `subprocess` is intended to replace `system`.  It's more secure and provides methods like `Popen` that provide greater flexibility.

Comment: What if it's not a .txt file? What if you want to edit a .html file using default editor?

Comment: see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74589184/1497139 for addressing some of the comments

Answer (score 4):

The modern Linux way to open a file is using `xdg-open`; however it does not guarantee that a text editor will open the file. Using `$EDITOR` is appropriate if your program is command-line oriented (and your users).

Answer (score 3):

If you need to open a file for editing, you could be interested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434597/open-document-with-default-application-in-python).

Comment: (This caveat also applies to my answer) If viewer and editor are separate, this opens the viewer in 9/10 cases. Call it on a HTML file and the web browser will open it for *viewing*.

Comment: You're right, of course :) Maybe the OP will clarify which filetype she needs to handle..

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use the [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) module to do this. All the answers given so far for both this and the linked question are just the same things the [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) module does behind the hood.

The ONLY difference is if they have `$EDITOR` set, which is rare. So perhaps a better flow would be:

```
editor = os.getenv('EDITOR')
if editor:
    os.system(editor + ' ' + filename)
else:
    webbrowser.open(filename)
```

OK, now that I’ve told you that, I should let you know that the webbrowser module does state that it does not support this case.

> Note that on some platforms, trying to open a filename using this function, may work and start the operating system's associated program. However, this is neither supported nor portable.

So if it doesn't work, don’t submit a bug report. But for most uses, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

As the committer of the [python Y-Principle generator](https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/py-yprinciple-gen) i had the need to check the generated files against the original and wanted to call a diff-capable editor from python.
My search pointed me to this questions and the [most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1443128/1497139) had some comments and follow-up issue that i'd also want to address:

- make sure the EDITOR env variable is used if set
- make sure things work on MacOS (defaulting to Atom in my case)
- make sure a text can be opened in a temporary file
- make sure that if an url is opened the html text is extracted by default

You'll find the solution at [editory.py](https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/py-yprinciple-gen/blob/main/yprinciple/editor.py) and the test case at [test_editor.py](https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/py-yprinciple-gen/blob/main/tests/test_editor.py) in my project's repository.

**Test Code**

```py
'''
Created on 2022-11-27
@author: wf
'''
from tests.basetest import Basetest
from yprinciple.editor import Editor

class TestEditor(Basetest):
    """
    test opening an editor
    """
    
    def test_Editor(self):
        """
        test the editor
        """
        if not self.inPublicCI():
            # open this source file
            Editor.open(__file__)
            Editor.open("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442841/lauch-default-editor-like-webbrowser-module")
            Editor.open_tmp_text("A sample text to be opened in a temporary file")
```

**Screenshot**
[image: Screenshot of Atom Editor]

**Source Code**

```py
'''
Created on 2022-11-27

@author: wf
'''
from sys import platform
import os
import tempfile
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Editor:
    """
    helper class to open the system defined editor
    
    see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442841/lauch-default-editor-like-webbrowser-module
    """
    
    @classmethod
    def extract_text(cls,html_text:str)->str:
        """
        extract the text from the given html_text
        
        Args:
            html_text(str): the input for the html text
            
        Returns:
            str: the plain text 
        """
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, features="html.parser")

        # kill all script and style elements
        for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
            script.extract()    # rip it out
        
        # get text
        text = soup.get_text()
        
        # break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
        lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
        # break multi-headlines into a line each
        chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
        # drop blank lines
        text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)
        return text

    @classmethod
    def open(cls,file_source:str,extract_text:bool=True)->str:
        """
        open an editor for the given file_source
        
        Args:
            file_source(str): the path to the file
            extract_text(bool): if True extract the text from html sources
            
        Returns:
            str: the path to the file e.g. a temporary file if the file_source points to an url
        """
        # handle urls
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/45886824/1497139
        if file_source.startswith("http"):
            url_source = urlopen(file_source)
            #https://stackoverflow.com/a/19156107/1497139
            charset=url_source.headers.get_content_charset()
            # if charset fails here you might want to set it to utf-8 as a default!
            text = url_source.read().decode(charset)
            if extract_text:
                # https://stackoverflow.com/a/24618186/1497139
                text=cls.extract_text(text)
                
            return cls.open_tmp_text(text)
            
        editor_cmd=None
        editor_env=os.getenv('EDITOR')
        if editor_env:
            editor_cmd=editor_env
        if platform == "darwin":
            if not editor_env:
                # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390709/how-can-i-open-the-atom-editor-from-the-command-line-in-os-x
                editor_cmd="/usr/local/bin/atom"
        os_cmd=f"{editor_cmd} {file_source}"
        os.system(os_cmd)
        return file_source
        
    @classmethod
    def open_tmp_text(cls,text:str)->str:
        """
        open an editor for the given text in a newly created temporary file
        
        Args:
            text(str): the text to write to a temporary file and then open
        
        Returns:
            str: the path to the temp file
        """
        # see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8577226/1497139
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/3924253/1497139
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as tmp:
            with open(tmp.name,"w") as tmp_file:
                tmp_file.write(text)
                tmp_file.close()
            return cls.open(tmp.name)
```

**Stackoverflow answers applied**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/45886824/1497139
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/19156107/1497139
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24618186/1497139
- [How can I open the Atom editor from the command line in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390709/how-can-i-open-the-atom-editor-from-the-command-line-in-os-x)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8577226/1497139
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3924253/1497139