# Issue with loading online pdf in python notebook using langchain PyPDFLoader

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, langchain

I am trying to load with python langchain library an online pdf from: http://datasheet.octopart.com/CL05B683KO5NNNC-Samsung-Electro-Mechanics-datasheet-136482222.pdf

This is the code that I'm running locally:

```
loader = PyPDFLoader(datasheet_path)
pages  = loader.load_and_split()
```

```
Am getting the following error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 8
      6 datasheet_path = "http://datasheet.octopart.com/CL05B683KO5NNNC-Samsung-Electro-Mechanics-datasheet-136482222.pdf"
      7 loader = PyPDFLoader(datasheet_path)
----> 8 pages = loader.load_and_split()
     11 query = """

File ***\.venv\lib\site-packages\langchain\document_loaders\base.py:36, in BaseLoader.load_and_split(self, text_splitter)
     34 else:
     35     _text_splitter = text_splitter
---> 36 docs = self.load()
     37 return _text_splitter.split_documents(docs)
...
   (...)
    114         for i, page in enumerate(pdf_reader.pages)
    115     ]

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\****\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpu_59ngam'
```

Note1: running the same code in google Colab works well
Note2: running the following code in the same notebook is working correctly so I'm not sure access to the temp folder is problematic in any manner:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\benis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\test.txt', 'w') as h:
    h.write("test")
```

Note3: I have tested several different online pdf. got same error for all.

The code should covert pdf to text and split to pages using Langchain and pyplot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not succeed with this task using `langchain` on windows with their current implementation.  You can take a look at the source code [here](https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/blob/5cfa72a130f675c8da5963a11d416f553f692e72/langchain/document_loaders/pdf.py#L65).  Consider the following abridged code:

```py
class BasePDFLoader(BaseLoader, ABC):
    def __init__(self, file_path: str):
        ...
        # If the file is a web path, download it to a temporary file, and use that
        if not os.path.isfile(self.file_path) and self._is_valid_url(self.file_path):
            r = requests.get(self.file_path)

            ...
            self.web_path = self.file_path
            self.temp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
            self.temp_file.write(r.content)
            self.file_path = self.temp_file.name
            ...

    def __del__(self) -> None:
        if hasattr(self, "temp_file"):
            self.temp_file.close()
```

Note that they open the file in the constructor, and close it in the destructor.  Now let's look at the python documentation on [`NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) (emphasis mine, docs are for python3.9):

> This function operates exactly as TemporaryFile() does, except that the file is guaranteed to have a visible name in the file system (on Unix, the directory entry is not unlinked). That name can be retrieved from the name attribute of the returned file-like object. **Whether the name can be used to open the file a second time, while the named temporary file is still open, varies across platforms (it can be so used on Unix; it cannot on Windows).**

Answer (score 0):

Update the pdf.py (https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/blob/5cfa72a130f675c8da5963a11d416f553f692e72/langchain/document_loaders/pdf.py#L65)  file and make the NamedTemporaryFile not deletable (until the application exits)

```
self.temp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
```

Reference: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924117/how-to-use-tempfile-namedtemporaryfile-in-python#:~:text=To%20fix%20this%20use%3A%20tf%20%3D%20tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile%20%28delete%3DFalse%29,won%27t%20let%20you%20open%20it%20using%20another%20application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924117/how-to-use-tempfile-namedtemporaryfile-in-python#:%7E:text=To%20fix%20this%20use%3A%20tf%20%3D%20tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile%20%28delete%3DFalse%29,won%27t%20let%20you%20open%20it%20using%20another%20application).

alternatively, this is a PR that is open in langchain: https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/pull/5887/files

Answer (score 0):

you need `pypdf` installed

```
pip install pypdf -q
```

write a reusable `def` to load pdf

```
def load_doc(file):
    from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
    loader=PyPDFLoader(file)
    pages  = loader.load_and_split()
    print("pages",pages)
    return loader.load()
```

if you work locally, you pass the destination of the file as the `file` arg. but if you want to load online pdf, you pass the url

```
data=load_doc('https://datasheet.octopart.com/CL05B683KO5NNNC-Samsung-Electro-Mechanics-datasheet-136482222.pdf')
print(data[1].page_content)
print(data[10].metadata)
print(f'you have {len(data)} pages in your data')
print(f'there are {len(data[20].page_content)} characters in the page')
```