# Can't use read() for html2text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I'm making a Python program that searches a webpage for a word. Although, when I try

```
website = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
content = website.read()
website.close()
test = html2text.html2text(content)
print(test)
```

I get this error :

```
test = html2text.html2text(content)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-    packages/html2text/__init__.py", line 840, in html2text
return h.handle(html)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-  packages/html2text/__init__.py", line 129, in handle
self.feed(data)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/html2text/__init__.py", line 125, in feed
data = data.replace("</' + 'script>", "</ignore>")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I'm new to Python, so I'm not sure how to deal with this error.
**Python 3.5, Mac.**

Answer (score 3):

`decode()` the content with the charset sent inside the `Charset` header ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19156107/771848)):

```
resource = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
content = resource.read()
charset = resource.headers.get_content_charset()
content = content.decode(charset)
```

<sup>Works for me (Python 3.5, Mac OS).</sup>

Comment: I got this error : `charset = resource.headers.get_content_charset()
AttributeError: module 'resource' has no attribute 'headers'`

Comment: @Kamdroid are you sure you are trying that on Python 3.5?

Comment: It said `Python 2.7.10`, weird. I did download Python 3 though. Maybe it's because before downloading v3 I downloaded v2? Although I deleted the Python 2 folder before downloading v3. But I have the Python Folder that's labelled Python 3.5.

Comment: @Kamdroid have you tried running it as `python3.5`?

Comment: Huh? I only have Python 3.5 apps, I think. What's the directory for Python 2?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is running on Python 3.5 as it includes `3.5.1` at the end of the file name in window