# urllib.request.urlopen return bytes, but I cannot decode it

Tags: python, python-3.x, decode, urllib, urlopen

I tried parsing a web page using `urllib.request`'s `urlopen()` method, like:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
req = Request(url)
html = urlopen(req).read()
```

However, the last line returned the result in bytes.

So I tried decoding it, like:

```
html = urlopen(req).read().decode("utf-8")
```

However, the error occurred:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte.

With some research, I found [one related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981977/how-to-handle-response-encoding-from-urllib-request-urlopen), which parses `charset` to decide the decode. However, the page doesn't return the charset, and when I tried checking it on Chrome Web Inspector, the following line was written in its header:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

So why can I not decode it with `utf-8`? And how can I parse the web page successfully?

The web site URL is `http://www.vogue.com/fashion-shows/fall-2016-menswear/fendi/slideshow/collection#2`, where I want to save the image to my disk.

Note that I use Python 3.5.1. I also note that all the work I wrote above have functioned well in my other scraping programs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The content is compressed with `gzip`. You need to decompress it:

```
import gzip
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request(url)
html = gzip.decompress(urlopen(req).read()).decode('utf-8')
```

If you use [`requests`](http://python-requests.org/), it will uncompress automatically for you:

```
import requests
html = requests.get(url).text  # => str, not bytes
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you share how you can get to know it is gzip?

Comment: @Blaszard the duplicate has that

Comment: @Blaszard, `urlopen(req).info()['content-encoding']`