# How to get a webpage with unicode chars in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, urllib2, windows-1255

I am trying to get and parse a webpage that contains non-ASCII characters (the URL is http://www.one.co.il). This is what I have:

```
url = "http://www.one.co.il"
req = urllib2.Request(url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
encoding = response.headers.getparam('charset') # windows-1255
html = response.read() # The length of this is valid - about 31000-32000,
                       # but printing the first characters shows garbage -
                       # '\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', instead of
                       # '<!DOCTYPE'
html_decoded = html.decode(encoding)
```

The last line gives me an exception:

```
File "C:/Users/....\WebGetter.py", line 16, in get_page
  html_decoded = html.decode(encoding)
File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1255.py", line 15, in decode
  return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0xdb in position 14: character maps to <undefined>
```

I tried looking at other related questions such as [urllib2 read to Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020892/urllib2-read-to-unicode) and [How to handle response encoding from urllib.request.urlopen()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981977/how-to-handle-response-encoding-from-urllib-request-urlopen) , but didn't find anything helpful about this.

Can someone please shed some light and guide me in this subject? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0x1f 0x8b 0x08 is the magic number for a gzipped file. You will need to decompress it before you can use the contents.

Comment: Are there any other such "surprises" I should be looking for in responses? Is there a way to transparently get a page including all needed post-processing, so that I see it like in Chrome's view-source?

Comment: I'm sure someone has handled that. Look around.