# Celery change content_encoding

Tags: python, django, celery

I want make apply_async task with celery, but my argument is a file with encoding in ISO-8859-1, but celery serializer data with UTF-8.

I recive the file from one url using this code:

```
    import urllib

    data = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    content = data.read()
    update_task.apply_async([content])
```

When I try call the method I have this erro:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte

Answer (score 1):

You should decode url response like `content.decode('ISO-8859-1')` before passing it to apply_async. Or pass just url to celery queue and make request to this url in task function

For more info about decoding urlopen response [read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981977/how-to-handle-response-encoding-from-urllib-request-urlopen)

Comment: i want one way that need not modificate the task, but I'm starting to think that is best i change