# How can I create a tmp file in Python?

Tags: python

I have this function that references the path of a file:

```
some_obj.file_name(FILE_PATH)
```

where FILE_PATH is a string of the path of a file, i.e. `H:/path/FILE_NAME.ext`

I want to create a file FILE_NAME.ext inside my python script with the content of a string:

```
some_string = 'this is some content'
```

How to go about this? The Python script will be placed inside a Linux box.

Comment: Open with 'w' and then close it, use `os.touch(fname)`.

Comment: Why do you need the temporary file then?

Comment: I have a function that calls the FILE_PATH of the object so it needs to be there

Answer (score 106, accepted):

There is a [`tempfile` module](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html) for python, but a simple file creation also does the trick:

```
new_file = open("path/to/FILE_NAME.ext", "w")
```

Now you can write to it using the `write` method:

```
new_file.write('this is some content')
```

---

With the `tempfile` module this might look like this:

```
import tempfile

new_file, filename = tempfile.mkstemp()

print(filename)

os.write(new_file, "this is some content")
os.close(new_file)
```

With `mkstemp` you are responsible for deleting the file after you are done with it. With other arguments, you can influence the directory and name of the file.

---

**UPDATE**

As rightfully pointed out by [Emmet Speer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2649287/emett-speer), there are [security considerations](https://security.openstack.org/guidelines/dg_using-temporary-files-securely.html) when using `mkstemp`, as the client code is responsible for closing/cleaning up the created file. A better way to handle it is the following snippet (as taken from the link):

```
import os
import tempfile

fd, path = tempfile.mkstemp()
try:
    with os.fdopen(fd, 'w') as tmp:
        # do stuff with temp file
        tmp.write('stuff')
finally:
    os.remove(path)
```

The `os.fdopen` wraps the file descriptor in a Python file object, that closes automatically when the `with` exits. The call to `os.remove` deletes the file when no longer needed.

Comment: This should really be updated to provide the secure way of creating tempfiles in python. Here is some examples. https://security.openstack.org/guidelines/dg_using-temporary-files-securely.html

Comment: Shouldn't you also `fd.close()` in the `finally` block? Check the docs for os remove regarding removing files still in use - https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove

Comment: @NelsonRodrigues the "with" keyword automatically closes the file aliased after executing the inner code

Comment: @ganski oh I see, I thought it just closed the `tmp` object. I tested it and it also closed `fd`.

Comment: How do I select the type of file that I am creating?

Comment: Also I write to the file but when I try to print(tmp.read()) I get empty field. I changed the 'w' to 'w+'

Comment: Add `tmp.flush()` after `tmp.write()` before trying to read the temp file.

Answer (score 253):

I think you're looking for a [`tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile).

```
import tempfile
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
    print(tmp.name)
    tmp.write(...)
```

But:

> Whether the name can be used to open the file a second time, while the named temporary file is still open, varies across platforms (it can be so used on Unix; it cannot on Windows NT or later).

If that is a concern for you:

```
import os, tempfile
tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
try:
    print(tmp.name)
    tmp.write(...)
finally:
    tmp.close()
    os.unlink(tmp.name)
```

Comment: this is a good answer based on the subject of the question, which google takes note of, rather than SuperString's particular problem

Comment: and you can pass an optional `dir=path` arg to `NamedTemporaryFile` if you want to control which directory it allocates it in.

Comment: do you need to do os.unlink(tmp.name)? isn't the point of using tempfile to handle cleanup?

Comment: is there any chance that tempfile will create two files with the same name simultaneously? If yes, will the first file get overridden? (consider that I have multiple users which can call the function simultaneously)

Answer (score -1):

Since Python 3.12, there's a proper way to write to a temp file, then read from it (snippet taken from https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/tempfile.html#examples):

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete_on_close=False) as fp:
    fp.write(b'Hello world!')
    fp.close()

    # the file is closed, but not removed
    # open the file again by using its name
    with open(fp.name, mode='rb') as f:
        f.read()

# file is now removed since it exits from `with`
```

If you want to create a text file instead of binary, use `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+t', delete_on_close=False)` instead.