# Python3: os system capture reading from / writing to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm writing an application which requires using a 3rd party shell script.

This shell script `some-script` processes an input file `--ifile` and saves the results in an output file `--ofile`.

So currently I can write/read to a tmp file and delete them afterwards

```py
import os

ifile_name = '/tmp/ifile.txt'
ofile_name = '/tmp/ofile.txt'

with open(ifile_name, 'w') as f:
    # write data to ifile for 'some-script'


# format command
command = 'some-script --ifile {ifile} --ofile {ofile}'.format(
    ifile=ifile_name,
    ofile=ofile_name
)

os.system(command)

with open(ofile_name, 'r') as f:
    # read in data from ofile

# clean up and delete tmp files
```

Is there a way I can directly pass python data to `--ifile` (e.g. by `'\n'.join(arr)`) and have the `--ofile` stream result as back in script without reading to / writing from files? and just string parse?

Comment: [How can I create a tmp file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577137/how-can-i-create-a-tmp-file-in-python)

Comment: @VaradarajuG the point is to not use a temp file at all and just stream

Answer (score 0):

The script will return its output to stdout and the py script will read it via PIPE

```
with Popen(["your_script_here"], stdout=PIPE) as proc:
    log.write(proc.stdout.read())
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work for me... basically if I take what you have and break the command up to `['bashCommand', '--ifile', ifile, '--ofile', ofile]` then `print(proc.stdout.read())` is `b''`