# Why is tempfile.TemporaryFile showing invalid path on AWS ECS/docker?

Tags: python, windows, docker, amazon-ecs, temporary-files

I am surprised to see very different behavior of `tempfile.TemporaryFile()` on Windows vs. Linux.

As is best pratice, I am using Python's `tempfile` module, as also suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577137/how-can-i-create-a-tmp-file-in-python).

Intent: I want to create a temporary file, and pass its name/path to some function (not the file object).
The following code works fine on Windows (Win 10, Python 3.8.6), but fails in a docker container on Amazon ECS (`python:3.8.6-slim-buster`).

```
import tempfile
import boto3

with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as tmpfile:
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    s3.download_file("my_bucket", "my_object", tmpfile.name)
```

This code fails not for S3 access rights/roles (that's all ok), but indeed due to the file name being invalid! A valid file name is produced on Windows (see output below), but is clearly invalid in the docker container on ECS:

- Windows: `tmpfile.name: C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\tmppky63n59`
- Docker/ECS: `tmpfile.name: 6`

Why does `tempfile.TemporaryFile().name` produce valid output in one case, but no the other? How can I fix it?

Comment: There is no guarantee that `TemporaryFile` creates an actual file. If you need a file with a name, use `NamedTemporaryFile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because for [tempfile.TemporaryFile()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html):

> The returned object is a true file object on POSIX platforms. On other platforms, it is a file-like object whose file attribute is the underlying true file object.

instead, you should use [tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile):

> This function operates exactly as TemporaryFile() does, except that the file is guaranteed to have a visible name in the file system (on Unix, the directory entry is not unlinked). That name can be retrieved from the name attribute of the returned file-like object.

so:

```py
import tempfile
import boto3

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmpfile:
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    s3.download_file("my_bucket", "my_object", tmpfile.name)
```

Comment: What's the point of `TemporaryFile` then, anyway? Seems like it's only coming with the downside of not guaranteeing to provide a valid name... Performance?

Comment: Indeed, if Python can get away with using a simple memory buffer without hitting the disk, it will be like 1000x more performant.