# How do I get the HTML of a web page if I have the url in python

Tags: python, file, url

So let's say I have this URL: https://www.python.org/
and I want to download the page's source into a .txt file named python_source.txt

how would I do that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138614/read-url-in-python and read up on `import urllib`

Comment: **How did this even manage to get an upvote ?**

Comment: web search is your friend

Comment: There are many ways to read a url's content in Python. There's no harm in putting them all here.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code design and writing service. You need to show some effort into doing the work yourself before you can expect any assistance from us. As it stands your question is likely to be voted down and closed as not showing enough research on your part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use urllib2, Here's how it's done:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
content = response.read()
```

Now you can save the content in any text file.

Comment: damn.. pyhton has everything..

Answer (score 0):

The python package [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/urllib2.html) does just this. The documentation gives a very clear example on what you want to do.

```
import urllib.request
local_filename, headers = urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://python.org/')
html = open(local_filename)
```