# How to read the first line of a file on a web server into a string using ftp?

Tags: python, ftp

I have a file ("public_html/try.dat") in my domain. I would like to read the first line of the file, without writing it out to disk.

```
import ftplib
string = ''
session = ftplib.FTP('xxx.com.au','user',"password")
session.storlines('RETR public_html/try.dat', string)    
print (string)
session.quit()
```

The code above gives me an error on the 4th line:
   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readline'

*** A word of explanation ***

I would like to send/receive a string between two different remote computers on the internet. Unfortunately my (cable) modem does not allow port forwarding, so I am forced to find another way, and the above is the only easy way I could think of. Stupid I know...

Comment: Do you have to use FTP? You could also read a file online using `urllib`

Comment: Can you give me an example ?

Comment: sure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138614/how-can-i-read-the-contents-of-an-url-with-python