# How to read remote page content using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I need to read the remote file content using python but here I am facing some challenges. My code is below:

```
import subprocess

path = 'http://securityxploded.com/remote-file-inclusion.php'
subprocess.Popen(["rsync", host-ip+path],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in ssh.stdout:
    line
```

Here I am getting the error `NameError: name 'host' is not defined`. I could not know what should be the `host-ip` value because I am running my Python file using terminal(`python sub.py`). Here I need to read the content of the `http://securityxploded.com/remote-file-inclusion.php` remote file.

Comment: What do you mean by `host-ip+path`? Anyway, take a look at [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Comment: Try `urllib` have a look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138614/how-can-i-read-the-contents-of-an-url-with-python) question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read the contents of an URL with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138614/how-can-i-read-the-contents-of-an-url-with-python)

Comment: @bereal : I just gave one example but my need is how to read the remote file content.

Comment: @satya Mean.? Do you want to connect the remote server?

Comment: @mkHun : yes my need is to test the `remote file Vulnerabilities` by including the remote files.

Answer (score 1):

You need the urllib library. Also you are using parameters which you don't use.
Try something like this:

```
import urllib.request

fp = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
mybytes = fp.read()

mystr = mybytes.decode("utf8")
fp.close()
print(mystr)
```

Note: this is for python 3

For python 2.7 use this:

```
import urllib

fp = urllib.urlopen("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
myfile = fp.read()
print myfile
```

Comment: I am using python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to read remote content via http.

requests or urllib2 are both good choice.

for Python2, use requests.

```
import requests
resp = requests.get('http://example.com/')
print resp.text
```

will work.