# Reading webpages Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

Very new to Python and struggling to get the hang of it, im needing to retrieve a webpage via its url, and return its contents. The contents will  be parsed later to find hyperlinks etc using regular expressions. (Im not wanting to use beautifulsoup)

```
import urllib.request
url = "http://stackoverflow.com"
f = urllib.urlopen(url)
print (f.read())
```

I realise my answer is probably very wrong but any pointer in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Either explicitly import `urlopen`, or use `f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read the contents of an URL with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138614/how-can-i-read-the-contents-of-an-url-with-python)

Answer (score 1):

In python 3.6 urlopen is in urllib.request module.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "http://stackoverflow.com"
f = urlopen(url)
print (f.read())
```