# How to save webpage data to a variable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, rss

I've been looking around for a while to find the answer but unfortunately no luck today.

I'm trying to get the contents off this webpage and save it to a variable. [(Link to the website)](http://rivalregions.com/rss/all)

Any help would be great, if you are confused what I am meaning drop a question in the comments, because personally I'm not sure how to word this well.

Please don't let me down stackoverflow, I know you can do it ;)

Comment: I don't get what you need...
If you want just a dump of the site, you can curl it: `curl http://rivalregions.com/rss/all > site` from terminal will store all the site in a file called `site`.

Comment: That just gives me invalid syntax.

Comment: Which OS do you run?
In windows you have to manually download and install it.
In Linux, depending on your distro, you may need to install it first either.

Comment: Right at this moment in time I'm using kali linux. But I usually use Windows 10.

Comment: `apt install curl`, then `curl http://rivalregions.com/rss/all > file`

Comment: `code`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
curl is already the newest version (7.55.1-1)`code`. It is already installed.....

Comment: @NathanWatson He is suggesting that you do the task on the Linux command line, which does belong more [on Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) than here.

Comment: Look at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html#fetching-urls), it is in there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read the contents of an URL with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138614/how-can-i-read-the-contents-of-an-url-with-python)

Comment: @NathanWatson Please mark my answer as correct if it worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to install requests. Hopefully you know `pip` otherwise please read up on it and install it.

`pip install requests`

then in your code:

```
import requests

url = "http://rivalregions.com/rss/all"

req = requests.get(url)

if req.status_code in [200]:
    html = req.text
else:
    print 'Could not retrieve: %s, err: %s - status code: %s' % (url, req.text, req.status_code)
    html = None
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install requests to get this to work in python3.
The below code was tested using python 3.6.10

```
import urllib.request

def print_some_url():
    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.python.org/') as f:
           a_variable = f.read().decode('utf-8')
           print(a_variable)
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
       print(e.reason)

print_some_url()
```