# How to read Wav file from url in python

Tags: python, url, audio, speech-recognition

This is my code where I want to read an audio file from url. This code gives me an error.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
audio = sr.AudioFile('http://www.wavsource.com/snds_2018-06-03_5106726768923853/people/comedians/carlin_logic.wav')
with audio as source:
   audio = r.record(source)
```

Error:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'http://www.wavsource.com/snds_2018-06-03_5106726768923853/people/comedians/carlin_logic.wav'
```

I also have another piece of code, i want help in reading audio file from url here also.

```
from watson_developer_cloud import SpeechToTextV1
file = 'http://www.wavsource.com/snds_2018-06-03_5106726768923853/people/comedians/carlin_logic.wav'
with open(file,
             'rb') as audio_file:
 data = speech_to_text.recognize(
      audio=audio_file,
      countinuous = True,
      content_type='audio/wav',
      interim_results = True,
      smart_formatting = True,
      timestamps=True,
      speaker_labels = True)
```

Error:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'http://www.wavsource.com/snds_2018-06-03_5106726768923853/people/comedians/carlin_logic.wav'
```

Comment: Share the error, so we can help you.

Comment: @PyMatFlow okay, i included the error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read the contents of an URL with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138614/how-can-i-read-the-contents-of-an-url-with-python)

Comment: You need urlopen instead of open.

Comment: @ Nickolay Shmyrev  i tried the following but it gave me  HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
audio1 = 'http://www.wavsource.com/snds_2018-06-03_5106726768923853/people/comedians/carlin_logic.wav'
import urllib2
mp3file = urllib2.urlopen(audio1)