# Can python 'read' and identify' parts of a code in the page source within the webbrowser, without having to save the webpage?

Tags: scripting

Can python 'read' and identify' parts of a code in the page source within the webbrowser, without having to save the webpage? For example, if I hit page source, I can search it and find the tags that I need without downloading the webpage to my harddrive. Is this something that python is able to do as well or would I need to download the page source first for idle to be able to analyze it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't quite redundant, but I believe it is [answered nicely here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138614/how-can-i-read-the-contents-of-an-url-with-python)
Python is indeed able to open a URL directly much like a file, and read from it there, so you don't need to manually save locally and open that file.