# How to convert a HTML report file into a PDF using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, wkhtmltopdf, xhtml2pdf

Below code is running successfully when I am passing HTML script in 'static_report'. How can I pass File name or URL in 'static_report'?

```
#Converting HTML To PDF
from xhtml2pdf import pisa

def convert_html_to_pdf(source_html, output_filename):
    # open output file for writing (truncated binary)
    result_file = open(output_filename, "w+b")

    # convert HTML to PDF
    pisa_status = pisa.CreatePDF(
            source_html,                # the HTML to convert
            dest=result_file)           # file handle to recieve result

    # close output file
    result_file.close()                 # close output file

    # return True on success and False on errors
    return pisa_status.err

static_report = ""
convert_html_to_pdf(static_report, 'report.pdf')
```

Comment: seems like you need to read a file as a string. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369219/how-to-read-a-text-file-into-a-string-variable-and-strip-newlines

Comment: or read a url as a string. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138614/how-can-i-read-the-contents-of-an-url-with-python

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried? What was exactly the error you got?

Answer (score 0):

Using the pdfkit library, you can convert HTML into pdf. HTML can be a local page or URL as given in this link.

[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-html-pdf/][1]