# Creating a list of dictionaries from a URL that points to a CSV

Tags: python

Hello and thanks in advance!

I have a url link such as: https://datasets/file.csv.  The csv file it points to looks like this:

```
a, b, c, d
1, 2, 3, 4
5, 6, 7, 8
```

From this data I need to produce a list of dictionaries such as:

```
[{'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', 'd': '4'},
 {'a': '5', 'b': '6', 'c': '7', 'd': '8'}]
```

I've tried this method:

```
from csv import DictReader
link = "https://datasets/file.csv"
with open(link, 'r') as read_obj:
     dict_reader = DictReader(read_obj)
     list_of_dict = list(dict_reader)
     print(list_of_dict)
```

However when I pass in my link, I get an invalid argument error.  I'm assuming:

```
with open("is expecting a file object", 'r') as read_obj:
```

Should I be converting my url link to some other type/object or is there just a better way of doing this?  Thanks again!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read the contents of an URL with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138614/how-can-i-read-the-contents-of-an-url-with-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- get the csv from url using `requests.get`
- Read the csv into pandas df using `read_csv`
- Convert the df to dictionary using `to_dict`

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests

link = "https://datasets/file.csv"
csv=requests.get(link).content
df=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv.decode('utf-8')))
records = df.to_dict(orient='records'))
print (records)
```