# How to receive url parameter value using python

Tags: python-3.x, api, url

I am new to python, i want to know in python how to receive the URL parameter value?
I tried with below code, but

```
import urllib.parse as urlparse
from urllib.parse import urlencode

url = "http://domainanme.com/api/filename.py?para_name=value"


url_parts = list(urlparse.urlparse(url))

query = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(url_parts[4]))
```

Using python i am unable to receive para_name = value
But in PHP can easily get URL parameter value using `$_GET['para_name']`, with out knowing the full URL, but in python how do i know the full URL with params

Note: i want to do using core python without any Python framework

Comment: I do not see the problem, this code returns: `{'para_name': 'value'}`  (see: https://onlinegdb.com/cxxsYR_MN ), This `print(query['para_name'])` will also return just `value`.

Comment: Yes, but my question is how the python will know the full url with parameter? basically python will respond back based on query parameter value. Value will be dynamic right, Basically python will know only parameter name

Comment: This question seems to be a duplicate of [Retrieving parameters from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074803/retrieving-parameters-from-a-url), and when it's not than it should be made clearer.

Comment: the question is not duplicate one, without the URL, how to receive the parameter value in python

Comment: [How can I read the contents of an URL with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138614/how-can-i-read-the-contents-of-an-url-with-python) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you

```
cgi.FieldStorage()
```

It returns a dictionary with the key as the field and value as its value.

Without any python framework, you can get the URL parameter value

Sample code

```
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable() # Optional; for debugging only

print("Content-Type: text/html")

arguments = cgi.FieldStorage()
for i in arguments.keys():

    print(arguments[i].value)
```

Example: save this file as `test.py` and execute it in your browser
like http://youdomainname.com/test.py?name=john
in the browser, you can see the result as a `john`

Comment: Yes, this is want i was looking, Finally I got solution, Thank you Vetrivel for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
  import urllib.parse as urlparse
  from urllib.parse import urlencode

  url = "http://domainanme.com/api/filename.py?para_name=value"

  url_parts = urlparse.urlparse(url)

  query = urlparse.parse_qs(url_parts.query)

  value = query['para_name']
```

You can access the query string from the `query` attribute of the `ParseResult` object. Then just access the value by key name.

Comment: Hi, how python knows http://domainanme.com/api/filename.py?para_name=value full URL with params, i hope param value will be dynamic right?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you make it clearer what you are trying to ask?

Comment: I mean in the first place how the python will know the url with dynamic parameter value? because the request will be coming from client right, basically an API call request

Comment: Without a framework, you could use the http server module to capture the path from the client sending the request. Then, perform the same operations of parsing the URL. You still need to specify the parameter you wish to access.