# How can I open the Atom editor from the command line in OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line-interface, atom-editor

I have the Atom editor and was wondering how you can open a file or folder from the terminal in Atom. I am using a Mac. I am looking for a way to do this:

```
atom . (opens folder)

atom file.js (opens file)

atom (opens editor)
```

Is this possible and how do I set it up?

Comment: I'm so happy to see Atom forked by [Pulsar](https://pulsar-edit.dev/).

Answer (score 553, accepted):

When Atom installs, it automatically creates a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) in your */usr/local/bin* folder. However, in case it hasn't, you can create it yourself on your Mac:

```
ln -s /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/atom.sh /usr/local/bin/atom
```

Now you can use `atom folder_name` to open a folder and `atom file_name` to open a file.

Comment: If you get "File exists" and the Atom command still dose not work just delete it and type the command over again.

Comment: When I do this, it continues to run in the terminal.  Is there a way to be able to close the terminal after the command?

Comment: @jhamm sorry I don't understand what you mean. Just go ahead and close the terminal, it doesn't affect Atom in any way.

Comment: When I close the terminal, then my Atom editor closes down too.  It is like there is some process running in the editor still.

Comment: Doesn't work. All input in Atom editor is sent to the terminal session that opened the Atom app. I solved the issue by choosing "Install Shell Commands" under the "Atom" menu.

Comment: @jhamm try appending "&" so it would be `atom &`

Comment: I used this, then enter `atom .` in the terminal and no issue at all.

Comment: This is way faster then the default script on my Mac: `alias atom='open -a Atom'`

Comment: First I tried "Install Shell Commands" in Atom menu. It returned an error saying it couldn't create a new directory. I used user328's method and it worked perfectly.

Comment: You might need to create the `/usr/local/bin/` directory with `sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin/` and use `sudo` for `ln` like `sudo ln -s /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/atom.sh /usr/local/bin/atom`

Comment: i had to delete the link itself and also add /usr/local/bin to my path.  also i moved atom to the applications folder.

Comment: `atom .` will open the current directory.

Comment: I open atom via application and then the command works. But I wanted it to open without having an instance of atom open. The following method doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 761):

With the Atom editor open, in the menu bar:

Click *Atom* → *Install Shell Commands*

[image: atom-add-shell-commands]

You should expect to see:

[image: atom-commands-installed]

Potentially restart your terminal (I did it just out of habit and am not sure if you need to).

Comment: What happened to me was that `atom` and `apm` symlinks were pointing to the Downloads folder from where I ran Atom for the first time. Then after moving Atom to the applications folder the symlinks were broken and the Install Shell Command option was not able to notice it. What I had to do was to remove the symlinks and then select the Install Shell Commands from the Atom menu. There was no need to restart the console as the `atom` command worked immediately after selecting the option. I ran `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/atom` and `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/apm` from a terminal to remove the symlinks

Comment: Turned out you don't need to restart terminal.

Comment: My computer was getting mixed up with XCODE and I had to restart and that fixed the problem.

Comment: This command only works if I don't restart my MacBook Pro after `Install Shell Commands`

Comment: This should be the answer

Comment: For me, after removing the symlinks and trying ``Install Shell Commands`` again, it shows: ``The shell commands `undefined` and `undefined` are installed``. But after running it a second time, then it shows ``Atom`` and ``apm``.

Comment: rather than restart your terminal, you should be able to pickup the new commands (installed on your PATH) using `rehash` or `hash -r`

Comment: atom . stopped working for me. I ran an atom update and 'Atom Menu bar' -> 'Install Shell Commands' and that did the trick. I wish this would show as the top answer.

Answer (score 22):

Roll your own with [user3283997's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390709/how-can-i-open-the-atom-editor-from-the-command-line-in-os-x/22399909#22399909), or in Atom, choose the menu option *Atom* → *Install Shell Commands*. This creates two symbolic links in `/usr/local/bin`.

```
apm -> /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/.bin/apm
atom -> /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/atom.sh
```

The `atom` command lets you do exactly what you're asking. `apm` is the command line package manager.

Comment: I needed this to validate that I was pointing my aliases to the correct executables.

Answer (score 15):

For Windows 7 x64 with default Atom installation add this to your PATH

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.4.0\resources\cli
```

and restart any running consoles

(if you don't find Atom there - right-click Atom icon and navigate to Target)

[image]

Comment: OP is on Mac. I guess he requires a solution specific to Mac only

Comment: I agree, but since the word "Mac" is not in the title or tags, it appears in search for everyone, hence may be helpful for Windows users.

Comment: If you don't want to bind this to a specific release, just use the bin folder: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\atom\bin

Comment: @sbedulin OSX appears in the title as well a question tag.

Comment: The question has been edited, but I'm not going to remove the answer util it's helpful for others (personally I'm against editing questions which are 3 years old).

Answer (score 11):

The symlink solution for this stopped working for me in zsh today. I ended up creating an alias in my `.zshrc` file instead:

`alias atom='sh /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/atom.sh'`

Comment: same here, weird, I can't seem to understand why this happened.

Comment: amingilani if you have installed the terminal for use with the `zsh` rather than the `bash` you need to put this alias on the file `.zshrc`:
`vim ~/.zshrc`
or
`nano ~/.zshrc`
for edit the file and then put on the final:
`alias atom='sh /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/atom.sh'`
save the file and then:
`source ~/.zshrc`
for load.

Comment: this is great if you don't have administrator privileges on your machine +1

Comment: If you are using ZSH, uncomment the line `export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH` in ~/.zshrc and restart the terminal

Comment: sh: /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/atom.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: @AshokR maybe the app is still in your downloads folder? You could still use this approach with something like `alias atom='sh ~/Downloads/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/atom.sh'`

Answer (score 11):

On macOS you can add it to your `~/.bash_profile`

as

`alias atom='open -a "Atom"'`

and from terminal just call

`atom filename.whatever`

Answer (score 5):

Open the application by name:

```
open -a 'Atom' FILENAME
```

Comment: You can create an alias 

"alias atom='open -a Atom'" in your bash or zsh profile.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Install Shell command]

Go to your terminal and locate your directory. Run this command:

```
atom index.html
```

*index.html* is just an example.

Comment: What directory? Can you be more specific? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67910630/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 3):

For Windows 10 and the new release of Atom, I solved the problem by adding in my *environment variable* on the "PATH" row:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\atom\bin
```

Comment: What kind of environment variable (on Windows)? "System" or "User"?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [sbedulin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390709/how-can-i-open-the-atom-editor-from-the-command-line-in-os-x/34904518#34904518) (greeting, lovely Windows users!):

The general path on Windows should be

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\atom\bin
```

If you are using a **Bash emulator** like [Babun](http://babun.github.io/), you'd better checkout the shell files, which are only available in the real application folders.

```
/c/User/<username>/AppData/Local/atom/app-<version>/resources/cli/apm.sh # Or atom.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

I’ve noticed this recently with all new Macs here at my office.  Atom will be installed via an image for the developers, but we found Atom is never in the *Application* folder.

When doing an *[ls](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ls)* on the */usr/local/bin folder*, the path for `atom` will show something like "/private/var/folders/cs".  To resolve this, we just located file *atom.app* and copied it into the application folder, and then ran the system link commands provided by nwinkler which resoled the issue.  Developers can now open Atom from the command line with "atom" or open the current projects from their working directory with "atom ."

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to put (move) "Atom" into the *Application* directory.

[image]

Comment: this is done automatically when installing correctly the package, which is my case as well, so Atom didnt create the sym link as mentioned in the accepted answer

Comment: In my case, this Atom is extracted into Downloads directory.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux && Mac OS-es type "atom ." in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution is to add */usr/local/bin* to your PATH environment variable. I had the same issue, and I installed shell commands (see [shaheenery's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390709/how-can-i-open-the-atom-editor-from-the-command-line-in-os-x/23666354#23666354)). The symbolic links already existed and were pointing to the correct destination (see [thomax's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390709/how-can-i-open-the-atom-editor-from-the-command-line-in-os-x/22710043#22710043)), however I would still get 'not found'. I'm using Korn Shell btw.

Here's what I did:

1. Open your *~/.profile* file using your choice of editor (in my case, `emacs ~/.kshrc`)
2. Add this line: `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:${PATH}"`
3. Save and exit
4. Restart terminal or `source ~/.profile`
5. Test with `atom -h`

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading Atom appears to break command line functionality on the occasion. It looks like in my case it created two versions of the application instead of overwriting them. It occurs because the new file structure doesn't match file paths created by *Atom* → *Install Shell Commands*. In order fix the issue, you'll need to do the following.

1. Move "Atom X" from Documents into Applications (why it ended up in here, I have no idea)
2. Rename "Atom X" to "Atom"
3. Might need to restart your terminal and Atom

After that, everything should work just like it did before.

Comment: Curious where you got Atom 3 from? Did you mean 1.0.3? According to their release page we're still in 1x.... https://atom.io/releases

Comment: @Susan So am I, not too sure why I wrote that looking back at it. Adjusted to make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

With [ConEmu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ConEmu) on Windows 10 I couldn't call `atom` from the console even after I added `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\atom\bin` to PATH in environment variables. I just added

```
alias atom="C:/Users/me/AppData/local/atom/app-1.12.7/atom"
```

to my `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue which I resolved by first moving Atom.app from downloads to Applications. Then under Atom's menu options, I selected "Install Shell Commands".

Answer (score -1):

I had problems due to Atom being unable to write its logfile when starting from the command line. This cured it.

```
sudo chmod 777 ~/.atom/nohup.out
```

Comment: This looks like an issue with your permissions. You shouldn't have to use `sudo` in your own home folder. Is it possible that you started Atom using `sudo` before? That would explain why the logfile had the wrong permissions. Check the ownership of the file and then change it to be owned by your own user (using `chown`).

Answer (score -1):

Add the path (:/usr/local/bin/) in the shell profile file.

Mac: file *$home/.bash_profile*

```
export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score -1):

I am on [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) Bash, so I have created the *~.profile* file with the following:

```
alias atom='~/AppData/Local/atom/bin/atom'
```