# Atom editor "permission denied" | OSX 10.9.4 Mavericks

Tags: macos, permissions, atom-editor

Just switched to OSX from windows, so sorry if this is a simple fix.

Every time I create a new file within Atom I get this error.

**EACCES, permission denied '{File Path}.'**

I have already changed the permissions of the actual app in the applications folder but does not seem to have worked.

I also noticed when I save files Atom Helper will prompt me for a password at random.

Obviously something is wonky.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Nvm, figured it out.

Turns out the particular folder was generated by Jekyll using "sudo" inside my shell script.

If I generate a new project sans sudo it works fine.

Comment: I had the same issue and thought it was a bug in vscode. Turns out I needed to change the folder permissions of the repo I was working on.

Answer (score 0):

Independent of what has caused the folder content to be not writable, a simple workaround is to open your file in Atom from terminal (like how described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390709/how-to-open-atom-editor-from-command-line-in-os-x)) but prepend `sudo` to open Atom as super user, e.g.

```
sudo atom myfile.txt
```