# Opening the atom editor from iTerm2 window is displaying - 'zsh: command not found: atom'

Tags: atom-editor, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

Just installed iTerm2 with oh-my-zsh, with atom already installed..

I have cloned a git repo of mine to use on an older laptop and for some reason oh-my-zsh is not opening my atom on the usual command.

```
➜  LandingPage git:(master) atom .
zsh: command not found: atom
```

Tried rectifying it by accessing and changing the .zshrc file but permission is denied. Anyone any suggestions?

Thanks,

Ant

Comment: Did you install zsh just recently, too, or have you been using it alongside Atom for a while? It's unclear from the question whether you installed zsh or oh-my-zsh (which is a package of settings for zsh).

Comment: I installed oh-my-zsh yesterday to work in iTerm2, wasn't sure there was anything else to do other than install oh-my-zsh, is there something else i need to install?

Comment: I was wondering whether you just recently installed *zsh*, itself, or the oh-my-zsh package, because that changes the situation. Not as much now that you've found a working solution, but keep it in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390709/how-to-open-atom-editor-from-command-line-in-os-x) it looks like atom may not have created a symlink to the atom command.

This has nothing to do with zsh -- the first argument is just telling you the shell, the information after it is the error.

For example on my machine (which doesn't have atom) when running zsh and trying to open a file with atom I get `zsh: command not found: atom`. When I try the same command with bash, I get `bash: atom: command not found`.

Let me know if the above link doesn't work! Hopefully this helps.

Comment: thanks! I followed the 'Install Shell Commands' in atom and ran '$ ln -s /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/atom.sh /usr/local/bin/atom', it told me that the file already exists however after restating it seemed to work :)

Comment: Glad to hear it!!