# Did I mess up my PATH? .bash_profile

Tags: bash, macos, path

I am trying to open up files from my terminal using `atom`. Which resulted in `-bash: atom: command not found`. I then followed, [installing the shell commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390709/how-to-open-atom-editor-from-command-line-in-os-x) from the editor. That resulted in `"EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir '/usr/local/bin'"` . I've previously tried to follow other recommendations on how to add the `subl` alias and I guess I tried way too many things, that I didn't understand. Could I have messed up my `$PATH` ?

When I echo my path this is what it is `/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`.

My **bash_profile** looks like this when I opened it with nano:

`export PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export EDITOR='subl -w'`

I don't remember if I added that first line when I tried adding `subl`.

Should I remove that? I'm also using a MacOS High Sierra.

**UPDATE** 
I removed what I had previously added in my `.bash_profile` and my path is now: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`.

I then ran the command: `sudo ln -s /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/atom.sh /usr/local/bin/atom` but got a `ln: /usr/local/bin/atom: No such file or directory` error

Comment: have you tried 'source .bash_profile' and then try your commands.

Comment: @jmh just tried that out. Then both the atom, and subl commands and it doesn't find them.

Comment: to run sublime text by typing subl i have the following line in my .bash_profile : ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl

Comment: try typing 'which atom' and see what you get. Probably nothing.

Comment: i see you have an answer.  i hope that helps you.

Comment: @jmh yep, I got nothing. I updated my question with the suggestions from the answer provided.  My path is now different. I also uninstalled atom and installed it again but face the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `export PATH` statement from your `.bash_profile`; it doesn't add anything that isn't already there. (Except maybe `/usr/local/sbin`, but I would remove that until you can demonstrate a need for it.)

Initially, `PATH` will include the directories listed in `/etc/path`:

```
% cat /etc/paths
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Any of your shell configuration files can add to the `PATH`. Assuming you haven't significantly altered your configuration, `/etc/profile` will run `path_helper` to add any directories listed in files under `/etc/paths.d`.

You only need to update `PATH` if you need to add a directory that is not already there. If `atom` is located in one of the above paths, you don't need to do anything. It *sounds* like you attempted to create `/usr/local/bin` when it already (as it should) exists, then perhaps did not ultimately create the symlink for `atom` under `/usr/local/bin`.

Try running just the `ln` command from the question you linked (using `sudo` if necessary), then confirm that `/usr/local/bin/atom` does indeed exist.

Comment: Okay I erased what was in my `.bash_profile` now my path is, `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`. 

I then ran the command: ` sudo ln -s /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/atom.sh /usr/local/bin/atom` but got a `ln: /usr/local/bin/atom: No such file or directory` error. @chepner

Comment: That's odd; it sounds like `/usr/local/bin` does not exist. Does `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin` still give you an error?

Comment: yeah it does.. it says: `mkdir: /usr/local/bin: Input/output error`. Also I resetted my `$PATH` by following the instructions [here](https://shellzero.wordpress.com/tag/reset-path-on-mac/) and now my `$PATH` is `/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin`

Comment: OK, the `PATH` is not the issue. The problem is that (for whatever reason) you cannot create the link to `atom.sh` that path lookup will eventually find in `/usr/local/bin`.