# How to ran files in Atom?

Tags: atom-editor

In Sublime Text, I ran files through cmd, but in Atom they open through Visual Studio 2019, how can I fix this? Please help with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 7 x64 with default Atom installation add this to your PATH

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.4.0\resources\cli
```

and restart any running consoles

(if you don't find Atom there - right-click Atom icon and navigate to Target)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/URPQk.png]

Source : [How to open Atom editor from command line in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390709/how-to-open-atom-editor-from-command-line-in-os-x)