# Launch default editor (like 'webbrowser' module) - Reposted

Tags: python, command-line, editor

Is there a (simple) way to launch the Windows default text editor from a Python script, like the webbrowser module?

NOTE: This is a repost of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442841/lauch-default-editor-like-webbrowser-module) but I don't feel like the question is being answered. I need to open Window's default text-editor without it necessarily being a *.txt file being opened. May it be .xml, .html etc.

For example:

I know that:

```
notepadexec = "C:/Windows/System32/notepad.exe {}".format(myfile)
subprocess.Popen(notepadexec)
```

will open the file in notepad editor even if `myfile` is a html file, but I want Windows default editor to somehow be chosen.

And yes, the following:

`os.system("{}".format(myfile))`

will open the file in Windows default editor **but** only if `myfile` is a text file. Aaand it will also open the default browser if it's a html file.

Clarifying the question with an example:
**How do I open a html file for editing purposes with Windows default text-editor in a python script?**

Comment: if you want to use the command line, then you have to make a function that parses the input_filename and then, depending on the extension, it will open it with the correct editor. Something like `if extension == '.txt': editor='notepad.exe'`  Also, notepad is an editor, the browser is not!

Comment: Maybe I'm not being clear... I'll read my question and perhaps edit it to be more clear

Comment: @alec_djinn I've edited to clarify the question.