# How to open a file with the standard application?

Tags: python, windows, linux

My application prints a PDF to a temporary file. How can I open that file with the default application in Python?

I need a solution for

- Windows
- Linux (Ubuntu with Xfce if there's nothing more general.)

#### Related

- [Open document with default application in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434597/open-document-with-default-application-in-python)

Comment: "The standard application"?  PDF Document Viewer?   Ghostscript?  gs?  Adobe Reader?  Do you want the OS to do the file-type to application mapping?  What are you asking for?

Comment: @S.Lott I think 'the standard application' is clearly a synonym for the default application, so let the OS decide which app to run.

Comment: @danio: It may be "clearly a synonym" to some.  The question, however, doesn't define "standard application" in any useful way.  I'd rather not assume, since other people will refer to this question in the future.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[os.startfile](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.startfile) is only available for windows for now, but [xdg-open](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-open.html) will be available on any unix client running X.

```
if sys.platform == 'linux2':
    subprocess.call(["xdg-open", file])
else:
    os.startfile(file)
```

Comment: in 2012, better use `sys.platform.startswith('linux')`

Comment: False. `xdg-open` isn't available on OS X. Further, `os.startfile` isn't on OS X.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: does [`webbrowser` module](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1684160/4279) work on OS X? ([it should use `open` command](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/webbrowser.py#l550) there)

Comment: @jfs yes i used it before switched to linux

Answer (score 10):

on windows it works with `os.system('start <myFile>')`. On Mac (I know you didn't ask...) it's `os.system('open <myFile>')`

Comment: On the Mac I actually did know how, but my application isn't going to run on Mac in the near future. ;)

Answer (score 8):

Open file using an application that your browser thinks is an appropriate one:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new_tab(filename)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if linux:
    os.system('xdg-open "$file"') #works for urls too
else:
    os.system('start "$file"') #a total guess
```

Answer (score 4):

A small correction is necessary for NicDumZ's solution to work exactly as given. The problem is with the use of 'is' operator.  A working solution is:

```
if sys.platform == 'linux2':
    subprocess.call(["xdg-open", file])
else:
    os.startfile(file)
```

A good discussion of this topic is at [Is there a difference between `==` and `is` in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python).

Comment: Thanks. I've edited his answer to correct that minor mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your favorite Application Framework for how to do this in Linux.

This will work on Windos and Linux as long as you use GTK:

```
import gtk
gtk.show_uri(gtk.gdk.screen_get_default(), URI, 0)
```

where `URI` is the local URL to the file

Comment: I'm using `Tkinter`... I can't see any similar function in it. `GTK` is definitely not my favorite application framework (`Tkinter` probably isn't either, but it's what I'm using for this project.)