# Launch default image viewer from pygtk program

Tags: python, linux, pygtk

I'm writing a PyGTK GUI application in Ubuntu to browse some images, and I'd like to open an image in the default image viewer application when it is double-clicked (like when it is opened in Nautilus).
How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know specifically using PyGTK but: `xdg-open` opens the default app for a file so running something like this should work:

```
import os
os.system('xdg-open ./img.jpg')
```

**EDIT:** I'd suggest using the `subprocess` module as in the comments. I'm not sure exactly how to use it yet so I just used `os.system` in the example to show `xdg-open`.

Comment: Useless use of `system`. This should be `subprocess.check_call(["xdg-open", filename])`.

Comment: The `subprocess` module is aimed at replacing older functions like `os.system`: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 3):

In GNU/Linux use `xdg-open`, in Mac use `open`, in Windows use `start`. Also, use `subprocess`, if not you risk to block your application when you call the external app.

This is my implementation, hope it helps: http://goo.gl/xebnV

```
import sys
import subprocess
import webbrowser

def default_open(something_to_open):
    """
    Open given file with default user program.
    """
    # Check if URL
    if something_to_open.startswith('http') or something_to_open.endswith('.html'):
        webbrowser.open(something_to_open)
        return 0

    ret_code = 0

    if sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
        ret_code = subprocess.call(['xdg-open', something_to_open])

    elif sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
        ret_code = subprocess.call(['open', something_to_open])

    elif sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        ret_code = subprocess.call(['start', something_to_open], shell=True)

    return ret_code
```

Answer (score 2):

GTK (>= 2.14) has [gtk_show_uri](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkmountoperation.html#function-gtk--show-uri):

```
gtk.show_uri(screen, uri, timestamp)
```

Example usage:

```
gtk.show_uri(None, "file:///etc/passwd", gtk.gdk.CURRENT_TIME)
```

**Related**

- [How to open a file with the standard application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679798/how-to-open-a-file-with-the-standard-application)