# How to call a default image viewer from Python

Tags: python

I need to be able to launch OS default image viewer on both Mac and Windows (possibly on Linux too). I would appreciate if you show how to do it simply and reliably.

Once again it is not known ahead of time what application needs to be used to open an image file. Neither the path to app executable is known. All of it should come as a response from OS to a request Python would make.

Ideally I would like to be able to open a default application for all type of files: not just for raster: for *.pdf it would be probaly Acrobat, for *.doc it would be OpenOffice, for *.html it is Chrome and etc...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12291324/650884