# Open file with pyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

There is a button.
When it is clicked, file `C:\file.txt` should be opened with default text editor (as if it is double clicked).
Is it possible in pyQt? Button is pressed -> file is opened.
All I can google is just dialogs, but I don't need them.

```
file = 'C:\file.txt'
widget.connect(button, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), ????)
```

How it can be done?

Comment: I think you're much farther from what you want than you probably expect. Do you have a PyQt GUI functioning and this is only a sample snippet, or is this your whole program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def openFile(file):
    if sys.platform == 'linux2':
        subprocess.call(["xdg-open", file])
    else:
        os.startfile(file)
```

And edit your 2nd line to:

```
widget.connect(button, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), openFile(file))
```

Code for opening file copied from [How to open a file with the standard application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679798/how-to-open-a-file-with-the-standard-application)

Comment: Why does file is started when I run script, no program (button) is showed? http://snipt.org/xJng . It is definitely has connection with `widget.connect` line

Comment: & Qiao: the source line `connect(..., openFile(file))` _will call_ openFile. Use `lambda: openFile(file)` to connect to a function that calls openFile, not to whatever openFile() returns. :)

Comment: just started new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046362/pyqt-running-slot-from-the-start . I relay have no patience ) `lambda:` is working, but it is a black box for me now.

Comment: @ Jacob : I tried your code but it is giving error as :NameError: global name 'subprocess' is not defined, please suggest

Comment: @lkkkk, please import subprocess before using it

Answer (score 1):

use this method with **lambda** and easily open any file you want

```py
self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda:os.startfile(".\help.png"))
```