# PyQt running slot from the start

Tags: python, pyqt

Why this script opens file as soon as it is launched? No program is showed.

It is supposed to open file when the button is pressed.

If I remove `widget.connect`, then everything is ok. But the button does not working.

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

# open file with os default program
def openFile(file):
    if sys.platform == 'linux2':
        subprocess.call(["xdg-open", file])
    else:
        os.startfile(file)

# pyQt
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

widget = QtGui.QWidget()
button = QtGui.QPushButton('open', widget)
widget.connect(button, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), openFile('C:\file.txt'))

widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What is wrong with this `widget.connect`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your connect line `openFile('C:\file.txt')` is a call to the function openFile. When you connect a signal to a slot you're supposed to pass a callable, e.g. a function but you're passing the result of openFile.

As you want to hard code the parameter to openFile you need to create a new function which takes no arguments and when called calls `openFile('C:\file.txt')`. You can do this using a lambda expression, so your connect line becomes:

```
 widget.connect(button, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), lambda: openFile('C:\file.txt'))
```