# Open PDF with default program in Windows 7

Tags: python, file, sys

I have a program in which the help documentation is in a .pdf in the same folder as the .py module. I need the program to open the .pdf with the system's default PDF reader.

I am using this code in my program:

```
if sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
    os.system("SlannanHelp.pdf")
elif sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
    os.system("SlannanHelp.pdf")
elif sys.platform.startswith('win32'):
    os.filestart("SlannanHelp.pdf")
```

However, when this is run in Windows 7, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\user\MousePaw
>   Games\MousePaw Labs\Slannan\Slannan.py", line 1286, in help_event
>       os.filestart("SlannanHelp.pdf") AttributeError: 'module' object
>   has no attribute 'filestart'

My guess is that os.filestart works in NT systems, but not in Windows 7. Is there a command that works for both, or one that just works for Windows 7? If the latter, how do I check to see if the user is running an NT or 7 version of Windows?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using os.system() in Windows?

Comment: I would try `os.system('start SlannanHelp.pdf')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is `os.filestart` does not exist at all.

You problably want `os.startfile`

You should also take a look at:
[Open document with default application in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434597/open-document-with-default-application-in-python)
and [How to open a file with the standard application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679798/how-to-open-a-file-with-the-standard-application) which recommend `system('open', filepath)` on mac and `system('xdg-open', filepath)` on linux

Comment: I'll try that. I was using the xdg-open and open functions, but for some reason, they vanished in the C&P...

Comment: It works! I can't find enough upvote buttons for your answer. Succinct, effective, and to the point. You solved my problem, AND pointed out another error in my file that I had missed. Thank you!!