# In python, how do you open a file or picture in a new window?

Tags: python

The content of the file or the picture should show up in a new window.

Comment: I'm assuming that you want to open a file with its default application. For example, given a .bmp, open Paint with that file. Is this the case? If so, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434597/open-document-with-default-application-in-python

Answer (score 4):

That will depend a lot on your operating system, since there are different programs on different systems to view images, etc. But one trick you might use is

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open(THE_FILE)
```

That should open up your default web browser pointed to the file, which will display images, and might do what you want for certain types of files.

Comment: Actually, it looks like on my system this opens the image viewer directly for images and PDF viewer for PDFs, so it might be even better for what you wanted than I thought.

Answer (score 2):

you could try

```
os.system("fspot picture.jpeg")
```

But, obviously, I'm assuming you're using fspot to view images, and that might only work in linux.

Check out the documentation for os.

-EDIT-
Mu Mind's solution works pretty well in Ubuntu Karmic. Not sure what it will do on a windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
os.system("start "+"anyfile.txt")
```

assuming you have windows. This basically opens the file in it's extension (For example if you had a .txt it would open in notepad.)