# Programmatically open a text file in R?

Tags: r

Is there something in R to open a text file? In Python, one could [open a text file using notepad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178154/open-a-text-file-using-notepad-as-a-help-file-in-python):

```
import subprocess as sp
programName = "notepad.exe"
fileName = "file.txt"
sp.Popen([programName, fileName])
```

Other methods are described in the post as well. Is there something similar in R?

Comment: You can use the equivalent code in R via `system` but neither solution is good: most systems won’t have “notepad.exe” installed (because most R systems aren’t Windows), and at any rate you should probably open the default editor, not an arbitrary one (however, I don’t know to achieve this portably in R, hence this is a comment, not an answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping in mind portability issues, i.e. this is specific to Windows, you can use `shell.exec`, which will open the file in whatever program is associated with that type of file by default - e.g.

```
## full path
shell.exec(paste0(c(getwd(), "/tmpfile.txt"),collapse = ""))
## relative to current working directory
shell.exec("tmpfile.txt")
```

both open `tmpfile.txt` in notepad on my machine.

Comment: I could then combine this with `if(Sys.info()["sysname"] == "Windows") shell.exec("tmpfile.txt")`. Sweet!