# File handling techniques in Python

Tags: python

How do I read a file by opening that particular file instead of printing it on the console? I've used the following code but it prints the contents of the file on the console.

```
fw=open("x.txt",'r+')
#fw.write("Hello\n")
#fw.write("Python is crazy af")
n=fw.read()
print(n)
fw.close()
```

Comment: `print(n)` prints the contents of `n`, which is the contents of the file after `n=fw.read()`. It is literally doing what you told it. If you don't want to print it... don't print it? "How do I read a file by opening that particular file" - you _did_ open that particular file, _and_ you _did_ read it. I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

The builtin `open` function makes the contents of a file available, meaning you can manipulate it with your code. If you don't want to print a line of it, you can do `.readlines()`. If you don't want to print it you can do anything else you want with it like store it in a variable.

One last note about file context:

```
with open("filename.txt", "r") as file:
     for line in file:
         # Do something with line here
```

This pattern is guaranteed to close, instead of calling `open` and `close` separately.

---

But if you wanted to open a text editor...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6178200/10553976

Comment: Thanks Charles I'll look into it!

Answer (score 0):

> How do I read a file by opening that particular file

The first 2 (non comment) lines of your answer do this:

```
fw=open("x.txt",'r+')
n=fw.read()
```

You have now read the contents of `x.txt` into the variable `n`

> instead of printing it on the console?

Don't print it then. Remove the line

```
print(n)
```

and the contents of the file won't be printed.