# How to open a file for browsing (as if one opened it manually)

Tags: python, windows, file, user-interface

I am trying to use Python to open a file for visual browsing, i.e. as if one double clicked a file to view it.  I have tried numerous searches but because the words are very similar with doing file I/O I could not come across the appropriate information.

I think this is a very simple question / answer and I apologize if the answer was right in front of my nose.

Ideally it would just be a call on a given file path and Python would know the appropriate application to pair in case it was an extension like .pdf.

Comment: You mean use Python to invoke Adobe Reader to open a pdf file, for instance?

Comment: This Question is a duplicate. Check:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434597/open-document-with-default-application-in-python][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434597/open-document-with-default-application-in-python

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/python-read-file-line-by-line-into-array

Comment: Many apologies for duplicating this question.  I think I lacked the proper vocabulary for describing this--all of what I pulled up before was File I/O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `os.startfile()`
2. `os.system()` but the parameters passed varies according to the OS

   `Windows: Start fileName
   Mac: open fileName
   Linux: oowriter fileName
        : gnome-open fileName
        : kde-open fileName etc...`

Example:

```
fileName="file.pdf" //Path to the file
1. os.startfile(fileName)
2. os.system("start %s")%fileName
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can use [`os.startfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#os.startfile).

```
os.startfile("C:\\Users\\your\\file.pdf")
```

Comment: Constraint is ONLY WINDOWS :(