# Any way to increase speed of closing a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a html-file and then upload it to my website using the following code:

```
webpage = open('testfile.html',"w")
webpage.write(contents)
webpage.close

server = 'ftp.xxx.be' 
username = 'userxxx'
password = 'topsecret'
ftp_connection = ftplib.FTP(server, username, password)
remote_path = "/"
ftp_connection.cwd(remote_path)
fh = open("testfile.html", 'rb')
ftp_connection.storbinary('STOR testfile.html', fh)
fh.close()
```

The problem is the `.close` command seems to be slower than the ftp connection and the file that is sent over ftp is empty. A few seconds after the ftp is executed I see the file correctly locally on my PC.

Any hints to be certain the `.close` is finished before the ftp starts (apart from using `time.sleep()`)?

Running Python 3.xx on W7pro

Comment: You forgot the parens after the first close, so it's not actually calling `close()`, just referencing it. Use `webpage.close()`.

Comment: yes that must be it, thanks for noticing!

Answer (score -1):

Try blocking on the close call:

[Blocking until a file is closed in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097674/blocking-until-a-file-is-closed-in-python)

By the way, are the parentheses missing on your close call?