# Opening an image file using Sikuli/Jython without clicking

Tags: python, jython, sikuli

I'm writing a script that saves an image file to the desktop (so "image.JPG").  After doing that, I want to open the image file so that it is displayed on the screen.  I've been trying to use subprocess (which I have no experience with), but can't seem to get it to work.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("C:/Users/first.last/Desktop/image.JPG")
```

However, that results in the following error:

```
[error] OSError ( Cannot run program "C:/Users/sean.sheehan/Desktop/image.JPG" (in directory "C:\SikuliX"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application )
```

I'm assuming this is because it is a file rather than an application (maybe I have to open an application that allows you to view an image?)

So, is there a way to open an image file in sikuli/jython/python without having to double click it with sikuli?  I'd also prefer not to download any additional packages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was a normal Python, you would use [`os.startfile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.startfile):

> Start a file with its associated application.

```
import os

filename = "C:/Users/first.last/Desktop/image.JPG"
os.startfile(filename)
```

But, the problem is that the are things (C-based functionality) that exist in Python, but are missing in Jython. And `os.startfile()` is one of these things.

[`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) should work in Jython:

```
import subprocess

filename = "C:/Users/first.last/Desktop/image.JPG"
subprocess.call('start ' + filename)
```

Also see more options at:

- [Open document with default application in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434597/open-document-with-default-application-in-python)

Comment: Cool.  Does that work in Jython, though? It worked using python on the cmd line, but doesn't seem to work in Sikuli (Jython). Either way, I looked into it and using "os.system(filename)" does the trick, so thank you.

Comment: @user2869231 yeah, correct, `os.startfile()` [does not exist in Jython at all](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/185801).

Comment: @user2869231 ok, done with edits now, `subprocess.call()` should work, please check.