# How to open python file in default editor from Python script

Tags: python

When I try on Windows
`webbrowser.open(fname)` or `os.startfile(fname)` or `os.system ('cmd /c "start %s"' % fname)`
my python script is getting executed.

How to open it for edit in default editor (like SQL script)

Edit:

```
import ctypes

shell32 = ctypes.windll.shell32
fname = r'C:\Scripts\delete_records.py'

shell32.ShellExecuteA(0,"open",fname,0,0,5)
```

it opens file explorer at `C:\Program Files\ibm\gsk8\lib64\C`

Comment: Are you asking about Windows? It thing [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should do the trick. It is available from various Win32 API wrappers like pywin32

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/435669/1909577

Comment: @myaut Sorry, it's on Windows.

Comment: @VinodSharma I do not see solution there

Comment: > tried < you should write "edit" instead "open" as second parameter of ShellExecute (of course it works if appropriate operation is defined in registry in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default **open** and **edit** actions are handled by [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WinAPI function (actions are defined in registry in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` subtree).

There are couple of way to access WinAPI from Python script.

1. Using nicer wrapper like [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/). It is safer than ctypes, but it is non-standard Python module. I.e:

   ```
   import win32api
   win32api.ShellExecute(None, "edit", "C:\\Public\\calc.bat", None, "C:\\Public\\", 1)
   ```
2. Using ctypes. It is trickier and doesn't control arguments, so may cause fault (unless you provide result type and arguments type manually).

   ```
   import ctypes
   ShellExecuteA = ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteA
   ShellExecuteA(None, "edit", "C:\\Public\\calc.bat", None, "C:\\Public\\", 1)
   ```

To check which actions are supported for desired filetype, do the following:

1. Run `regedit.exe`
2. Go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` and pick desired extension, i.e. `.py`. Read `(Default)` value on left pane - it would be class name, i.e. `Python.File`.
3. Open that class name subtree in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`. It should contain `shell` subtree, under which you will find available shell actions. For me and Python scripts they are `Edit with IDLE` and `Edit with Pythonwin`.
4. Pass these values as second parameter of `ShellExecute()`

Answer (score 3):

```
"""
Open the current file in the default editor
"""

import os
import subprocess

DEFAULT_EDITOR = '/usr/bin/vi' # backup, if not defined in environment vars

path = os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(__file__))
editor = os.environ.get('EDITOR', DEFAULT_EDITOR)
subprocess.call([editor, path])
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation of [`os.startfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile), you can define an operation to execute. So `os.startfile(fname,operation='edit')` shoudl work for what you want. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53672294).