# how to play a video after clicking a button on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a video play after a button is clicked, but its not working.
The error I get is 
SyntaxError
(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in positiion 2-3: truncated\UXXXXXXXX escape

```
rb1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Play", command=self.video).pack()

def video(self):
    import os

    os.system("C:\Users\Tim\Documents\Bicep.mp4")
```

Comment: What happens? What does "not working" mean? Do you get errors? Does it play the wrong video?

Comment: What exactly is the error

Comment: @BryanOakley hehe jinx, great minds think alike

Comment: can you show us the full code with `traceback` ?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434597/open-document-with-default-application-in-python

Comment: can you run video without `tkitner` ? if not then problem is not `tkinter`.

Answer (score 0):

Your quoting of the file path is causing this error. In python strings a backslash is used as an escape character to provide a means to enter special characters like newlines and unicode characters (eg: \u00a9 for the copyright character) . So the `"\Us"` sequence is translated into an attempt to read a unicode character definition that is invalid as 's' is not a hexadecimal digit. You should either escape the backslashes ("c:\Users\Tim\...") or use the raw string marker to indicate this string should not have escape code translations performed (ie: r"C:\Users\Tim..." ).