# Opening a file through a desktop application in python

Tags: python

I am creating a code which allows a user to scan an barcode, resulting in the correct file in the explorer they need to open on the computer. A BIG problem I have recently run in to: the files only open properly when they are opened through the application they run on.

My question would then be, is it possible to create a script which mimics opening a file through an application? Similar to being in excel and clicking File -> Open...
If this is possible, what would be the first steps in order to make it happen?

Comment: If the application has registered its extension properly, then you can just invoke the file as if it were a program.  Example, `os.system("abcdef.xlsx")` will open Excel on that file.  (I should caution -- that's Windows only.)

Comment: On Ubuntu-based systems, I believe `xdg-open` will work (also through `os.system`). Not sure about other Linuxes; it's probably different on each.

Comment: By "opened through the application", do you mean you can not double click and open the file, nor right click and select the app you want to use to open it?

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is unfortunately not possible with python. But you can open the files with their default application through a subprocess. Try following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434597/open-document-with-default-os-application-in-python-both-in-windows-and-mac-os).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using by pyqt library.
More information for pyqt: [What is pyqt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyQt)

For the Open File option on pyqt: [More about Qfile dialog](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_qfiledialog_widget.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, you might be able to use COM automation via win32com to have the program open the file if the program supports it. I know this works with the Office programs.