# Python - Launch Text File in User's Default Text Editor

Tags: python, html, text

I am writing a text-based application in Python 3.9.9 in VSCode on MacOS.

I am trying to write some code that will allow the user the option to launch a text file in his/her default text editor. The text file is going to serve as a Help file that the user can launch from my application, and then close when they are done or work with side-by-side the application.

I want to include the text file in the same directory as the main python app file or in a nested directory and provide a relative path to it.

I don't need to read or update the file. I just need to launch it.

I think the OS module or subprocess module may be the way to go, but I'm having trouble making it work with either....

Answer (score 1):

*Have you tried using [OS Module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)?, The functions that the OS module provides  allows you to interface with the underlying operating system that Python is running on*

*example*

```
import os
os.system("file.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to check this -> [Open document with default OS application in Python, both in Windows and Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434597/open-document-with-default-os-application-in-python-both-in-windows-and-mac-os).

---

**My solution**

```
import subprocess as sp
defEditor = "notepad.exe"
#note that r is essential to read the path
path = r"C:\x\x\x\text.txt" 
sp.Popen([defEditor, path])
```

You can make this a bit better, by using an if statement to identify the OS of the user, to then run the correct default text-editor.

```
import subprocess as sp
import platform
#Check the OS
OS = platform.platform()
#Check if "Windows" is substring of OS
if "Windows" in OS:
    defEditor = "notepad.exe"
    path = r"C:\x\x\x\testo.txt"
    sp.Popen([defEditor, path])
```

---

As far as i know, using os.system is discuraged because of security reasons, but more expert users can correct my statement.
Hope this helped