# Is there any function to open (directly open the file itself) any file?

Tags: python, file-handling

In python, `file handling` after creating a file and saving the file, is there any way to directly show the file to the user the same as opening a file by double-clicking it?

Comment: Duplicate of [Open document with default OS application in Python, both in Windows and Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434597/open-document-with-default-os-application-in-python-both-in-windows-and-mac-os)

Comment: This is OS- and destktop-environment-dependent.

Comment: "Do the same thing as double clicking" is not what I as a developer think someone means when they say "directly open the file itself".